# Upgrade to a processor not on supported CPU-s list

Tags: cpu, motherboard, upgrade

I'm about to upgrade a processor for my 4 years old system ([Gigabyte GA-M61PM-S2](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=2373), single core Athlon 64 3800+ 2,4GHz 90nm) to triple core AMD Athlon II x3 455 AM3 3,3GHz. But this processor is not on [supported processors list for this motherboard](http://www.gigabyte.com/support-downloads/cpu-support-popup.aspx?pid=2373) (latest supported X3 is 440@3.0GhZ which isn't available now in my country, I've only found 435@2,9GHz at almost the same price as 455).

Should I expect this 455@3,3GHz CPU to work on this motherboard or have to buy a slower processor?

Comment: You won't know until you try, but there's a very high chance that motherboard won't boot with any processor which isn't on the supported list. Also make sure to have newest BIOS version installed! This one is VERY important!

Answer (score 4):

As long as the socket matches, at least it will fit in physically.

However, new generations may have new features and interfaces your motherboard may not support. Hence the support list.

As the list states 440 and you want to use 455, I wouldn’t be sure it works, but rather that it does not. If the motherboard would support it, the vendor would surely like to list it in the supported list. So very probably, it will not work.

Updated BIOS versions often add CPU support for newer CPUs, but that probably happened for your Motherboard in the past and now it reached it’s physical max.

The only way to be really sure is to contact your MB vendors support and ask. They can tell you.